# Self-hosted SignalR in Windows .Net Service blocked by CORS on same server, works on other servers

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, signalr

I've been using a Self-Hosted SignalR Windows service accessed from multiple production servers (now in Azure) for 6+ years without a problem.  I created an identical server for development in Azure but when I'm accessing SignalR from a browser on the SAME SERVER, SignalR gives me the following error when using either http:6287 or https:6286:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myserver.learn.net:6287/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&xxxxxxx' from origin 'http://myserver.learn.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

However... It WORKS when connecting from OTHER SERVERS!  I'm starting the connection with no errors using:

```
SignalR = WebApp.Start("http://myserver.learn.net:6287/");
SignalRSSL = WebApp.Start("https://myserver.learn.net:6286/");
(also SignalR = WebApp.Start("*:628x/" for both);
```

In my client code, I include the following script:

```
<script src="http://myserver.learn.net:6287/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

When I enter that url (or https version) in a browser ON THE SAME OR DIFFERENT SERVER, it shows the ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.3.0-rtm page correctly!  I've turned off the firewall with no change, added Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener (someone suggested). I have also entered the wildcard certificate with netsh so the SignalR service can deal with the SSL connection using:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:6286 appid={12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf} certhash=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Edit: I've also tried changing the ipport value to the real internal IP of the server as well as the public IP but no change.

So, why can't I access SignalR from the same server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in another answer here that worked.  I changed:

```
$j.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
```

To:

```
$j.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true, xdomain: true }).done(function () {
```

Which worked for both internal and external clients.  xdomain:true alone didn't work but when I added jsonp:true it did.  I have no real idea why, just that it's working now.